# Add words to a text file using a single terminal command (no editors)

Tags: command-line, text, editing

I'm new to Linux. I need to edit a `.conf` file from the open terminal only and not using any text editors. That is, can I add words and sentences to a config file from an open terminal?

Example: `command /home/.../file.conf -add 'abcd'` to the 23rd line and so on. And finally, save it.

Is it possible to search a specific word in that config file and add new text to the next line of that config file using only the command?

Comment: Looks like `sed` can come to help.

Comment: Ask a single question.

Answer (score 55):

I usually do this way when I am programming my script to do same what you are asking but programmatically.

```
echo "Hello you!" >> myfile.txt
echo "this is 2nd line text" >> file.txt
echo "last line!" >> file.txt
```

Voila! You got it.  Important to note `>>` means adding new line to existing file meanwhile `>` just simply overwrite everything.

Comment: thank you for your prompt reply. But i need to add like more than 3000words to 23rd line of my .conf file sequentially. Is there any easier way?

Answer (score 23):

Adding words and sentences to a config file from open terminal can be easily achieved with sed.

```
sed -i '23iabcd' file.conf
```

inserts at line 23 the text `abcd` into file `file.conf`

`-i` does the modification directly to file `file.conf`.

If you want to use `awk` then:

```
awk -v n=23 -v s="abcd" 'NR == n {print s} {print}' file > file.conf
```

**The following adds one line after SearchPattern.**

```
sed -i '/SearchPattern/aNew Text' SomeFile.txt
```

It inserts New Text one line below each line that contains SearchPattern.

To add two lines, you can use a `\` and enter a newline while typing New Text.

```
 sed -i '/pattern/a \
line1 \
line2' inputfile
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the `printf` command.

To add lines to your file

```
$ printf "\nThis is a new line to your document" >> file.txt
```

To overwrite the file

```
$ printf "This overwrites your file" > file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{if ($1 ~ /regex/) print $1 "content to be added"; else print $1}' < inputfile > outputfile
```

Notes:

- regex is a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) (also known as regex), it defines the search criteria. Regular expressions allow for very customizable searches and the syntax understood by awk is [in the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Regexp). In the simplest case - search a string "as it is", character by character - just put a backslash before special characters (see manual for the list of special characters)

How it works:

- open `inputfile` for reading the input lines, clear `outputfile` and open it for writing the output lines
- for each line, run the block in braces:

  - if the line matches the regular expression, then output the line with content appended
  - otherwise, output the very same line.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my own question using the `ed` command

```
ed -s /home/.../abc.conf <<< $'23i\ntext\n.\nwq'
```

Text can contain 27 lines. You can copy 27 lines from a text file and paste 27 lines to your config file. But I need to run the `ed` command simultaneously in order to add more text to the same config file.